# Cannot Create a Asp.net MVC 2 project in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, web-platform-installer

I Installed Microsoft's Asp.net MVC 2 using the Web PI (on Windows XP) but it is never marked as installed!

i have found the "system.Web.Mvc.dll" in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 2\Assemblies" so i'm pretty sure it's indeed installed but i cannot create a new Asp.net MVC project in Visual Studio 2008 because the option isn't there...

The problem might be because, i installed VS2010 Beta at first but uninstalled it when i saw it might not be possible to use MVC2 with it

Comment: Is the problem that the option doesn't appear on the "New Project" dialog, or is it that it's there but doesn't work? I have the same problem with the Platform Installer, but I *can* create an MVC 2 project.

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, i was on a really outdated machine (which don't even have XP SP3) i updated .net framework 3.5 and now i have the option :)

Answer (score 1):

You can download the VS 2008 tools and it will install the appropriate VS templates for MVC 2.

ASP.Net MVC 2 RTM Download: 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9&displaylang=en